# MKDIR don't work. Not Upload

Tags: php, image, upload, mkdir

I have the code below:

```
            for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload_obra']['name']); $i++) {
          //Get the temp file path
          $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload_obra']['tmp_name'][$i];

           echo $tmpFilePath . "     tmpFilePath";
          //Make sure we have a filepath
          if ($tmpFilePath != ""){

            mkdir('images/fotos-geral/' . $ultimoID, 0700);
            mkdir('images/fotos-geral/' . $ultimoID . '/obra', 0700);

            $newFilePath = 'images/fotos-geral/' . $ultimoID . '/obra/' . $_FILES['upload_obra']['name'][$i];
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
                echo "rolou";

              //Handle other code here

            }
          }
        }

        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload_doc']['name']); $i++) {
          //Get the temp file path
          $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload_doc']['tmp_name'][$i];

           echo $tmpFilePath . "     tmpFilePath";
          //Make sure we have a filepath
          if ($tmpFilePath != ""){

            mkdir('images/fotos-geral/' . $ultimoID, 0700);
            mkdir('images/fotos-geral/' . $ultimoID . '/doc', 0700);

            $newFilePath = 'images/fotos-geral/' . $ultimoID . '/doc/' . $_FILES['upload_doc']['name'][$i];
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
                echo "rolou";

              //Handle other code here

            }
          }
        }
```

Exists two uploads of image in my form. Each one is of one upload specific.
But, the paste is not created! The upload don't  occurs. I have selected ten images, and it didn't work.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(-1)` to the top of your code and see what errors are returned.

Comment: where are you defining `$ultimoID`? If it's undefined, then you're trying to do `mkdir('`images/fotos-general') - which is pointless. you cannot create an unamed directory.

Comment: $query = "SELECT MAX(codObra) as ID FROM obra";
   $ultimoID = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
   $ultimoID = mysql_fetch_array($ultimoID);
   $ultimoID = $ultimoID["ID"];

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about using in your html form ?

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data"> </form>
```

Comment: Yep <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" name="form" class="rounded" method="post" action="catalogacao.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" name="formulario">